# Will there be an backport of Unity 6/compiz for Precise?

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10, backport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install Unity 6.x.x on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197941/is-it-possible-to-install-unity-6-x-x-on-ubuntu-12-04)

In my opinion Unity 5.x in precise is not how it should be in an LTS and I would like to know, whether Unity 6.x/compiz (as in quantal) will be backported to precise for a better performance.