# Is it possible to install Unity 6.x.x on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity, backport

Is it possible to get the latest Unity without upgrading to 12.10 on my Ubuntu 12.04 PC or will this be backported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can [get the latest version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity) and build it manually, I haven't tried this, but some people succeeded on doing it:

[How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)

Since it contains only some bug fixes, It's not that great updating it to version 6.

Answer (score 6):

This Works:

Open Terminal, then type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:benkai/precise-unity-backport

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-applications

sudo apt-get install unity

wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/benkai/precise-unity-backport/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-lens-applications/unity-lens-applications_6.4.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i unity-lens-applications_6.4.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

From:
https://launchpad.net/~benkai/+archive/precise-unity-backport

Answer (score 4):

An official backport won't happen, no.

Because Unity 6.0 depends on the latest Quantal versions of Nux and Compiz, which in turn depend on the newer versions of other libraries, like libunity-webapps, indicators, etc. Unity 5.x, however, will continue to be supported for the entire life cycle of Ubuntu 12.04 with stable release upgrades to fix bugs.

It would be possible for a community developer to take the source code of Unity 6.0 and dependent libraries, try building it with Precise libraries (many modifications would be needed) and put it up in a PPA, but it won't be worth the effort.

Comment: thank you...this is sad..because i would like to install the LTS on my friend's/family's computer, but with the performance bugs it's quite not that nice on some machines.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to give it a Google and found [this link](https://launchpad.net/~benkai/+archive/precise-unity-backport) referring to Unity backporting from Quantal to Precise which may be of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on dependencies, really. If the dependencies for 6.2 can be satisfied, then it is likely it will be backported to Ubuntu 12.04 in the near future.