# Will I be able to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 Unity to 12.10 version?

Tags: 12.04, unity, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install Unity 6.x.x on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197941/is-it-possible-to-install-unity-6-x-x-on-12-04)

Will there be upgrade for Unity (6.8.0) 12.04 to the same version of 12.10?