# How can I upgrade to Unity 6.8 without upgrading to 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install Unity 6.x.x on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197941/is-it-possible-to-install-unity-6-x-x-on-12-04)

I am running 12.04 and I want to upgrade just Unity without upgrading the version. Is this possible?

If yes, how can I do it??